# Is it possible to make a desktop app in matlab R2010b?

Tags: matlab, desktop

How can i create the app instalation file?I only found the answer for Matlab R2012b.Thx

Comment: It is new feature of Matlab available from R2012b version only.

Answer (score 0):

using mcc, you can create standalone executables. more information is available here: http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html.